# [VC++2015]: RTTI for some classes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, vc++2015

Для всего C++ проекта отключен RTTI, но он нужен выборочно для нескольких классов.

Как можно включить RTTI частично? 
Как указать это в настройках компиляции проекта?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912955/disable-rtti-for-some-classes

Comment: Там абсолютно обратная ситуация. )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Классы для которых надо rtti включить и отключить необходимо разнести по разным .h и .cpp файлам

2) Для msvc15 открываете Solution Explorer находите там в папке Source нужные .cpp файлы - пкм - properties (Выбрать конфиг и платформу) - c/c++ - all options, далее найти строку "Enable RTTI" и поставить "yes" (он же флаг /GR)

По умолчанию при компиляции студия использует конфигурацию проекта, однако для определенных файлов можно ветвить конфигурации.

Comment: для .vcxproj файла проекта это равносильно добавлению строки `<RuntimeTypeInfo Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</RuntimeTypeInfo>` в элемент `<ClCompile Include="YourFile.cpp">`. Condition определяет для каких сборок использовать.

Comment: А перечислить файлы опцией в Command Line как то можно?  P.S.Потому что маркировать файлы это можно забыть потом что они сконфигурированы как то по другому чем весь проект.

Comment: Если речь идет про command line проекта, то нет. Что касается забыть, то если на проекте часть файлов собирается с rtti, а часть - без, то такое лучше обозначить в документации.